# pandas tz_convert giving different offset for same timezone

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timezone, timezone-offset

I am trying to use `tz_convert` function of pandas timestamp object and there I am facing a strange issue. Let's say we have two timestamps, `Timestamp('2020-04-16 10:59:36.227000+0000', tz='UTC')` and `Timestamp('2020-01-29 20:02:32.483000+0000', tz='UTC')`. Now when I do the following:

```
obj1 = pd.Timestamp('2020-01-29 20:02:32.483000+0000', tz='UTC')
obj1.tz_convert('CST6CDT')

#Output: Timestamp('2020-01-29 14:02:32.483000-0600', tz='CST6CDT')


obj2 = pd.Timestamp('2020-04-16 10:59:36.227000+0000', tz='UTC')
obj2.tz_convert('CST6CDT')

#Output: Timestamp('2020-04-16 05:59:36.227000-0500', tz='CST6CDT')
```

Clearly, for the same timezone the time offset is different. Can someone tell what is the reason of this weird error? I am using pandas version 1.1.4

Comment: Note the [comment in the src](https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/master/tz/northamerica#L188) - don't use CST6CDT, better stick to IANA time zone names, e.g. `'America/Chicago'` for US central time (CST/CDT).

Comment: And to answer the question: The differences in UTC offset you observe are due to DST; US central time changed from CST (UTC-6) to CDT (UTC-5) on March 8th 2020.

Comment: @MrFuppes That was really helpful. Can you tell me what should be the pytz timezone for Central Dallas? Is it CST or is it something else?

Comment: You can use `America/Chicago` for Dallas as well; the name might be slightly misleading, it's not specific to Chicago. You could also use `America/Mexico_City` with to get the same result since it's also in US Central time zone. Here's a list of available time zone names: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).